# Reading custom date time formats with SAS

Tags: datetime, sas

I have a comma delimited data set whose first 2 rows is like this:

```
1/13/2010 21:09,3.3
11/30/2010 7:33,7.2
....
```

In trying to read the data in SAS, I have done this data step below:

```
data myDataSet;
     infile      'sampleData.csv'    dlm=',';
     input     timestamp     :mmddyy16.     value;
run;
```

Now that the data is now a SAS data set, I try to view it by doing:

```
data viewData;
     set     myDataSet;
     format     timestamp     date9.;
run;
proc     print     data=viewData;
run;
```

I observed that the timestamp column output only contains the date and not with the time. I want the timestamp to be read and displayed in a format like "dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS". How do I ensure that in reading the file, the informat is correctly specified and no component of the timestamp is lost?

Comment: Can you please give code line illustrations as to how to go about this particular problem? I have gone through the documentations but was not able to find direct answers.

Answer (score 0):

`MMDDYYw` is a date informat, not a datetime informat - it only reads days and larger and ignores the time.  It has a practical maximum length of 10 (although it allows up to 32) as a result.

You can use `MDYAMPM.` to read those two dates in, among other informats.  That might be the ultimately correct informat, or it might not, depending on the totality of your data; several NLS specific informats might also work.  See [the SAS informat documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm) for more details.